# Eliminate NoClassDefinationFoundError

Tags: java, build, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I have created a simple java project which uses vert.x verticles to deploy snmpTrapListner. But to run a verticle which listens snmpTrap i have to write

> vertx run com.vertx.traplistener.prototype.Starter -cp
>   VertxTrapListener.jar;Swapnil\VertxTrapListener\lib\snmp4j-1.10.1.jar

i have added snmp4j jar into my classpath and even it is also present in  VertxTrapListener.jar, but still i have to put it in command line otherwise i get

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/snmp4j/CommandResponder

error , Please help me so that all i have to do to run verticle is to write

> vertx run com.vertx.traplistener.prototype.Starter -cp
>   VertxTrapListener.jar

Comment: Where is your java command?

Comment: AS i am using verticles it is like this "D:\>vertx run com.vertx.traplistener.prototype.Starter -cp VertxTrapListener.jar;Swapnil\VertxTrapListener\lib\snmp4j-1.10.1.jar"

Comment: [this](http://vertx.io/manual.html#using-vertx-from-the-command-line) says you need prefix classes: before your jar name. Never used vertx before.

Comment: i just need to remove that snmp4j jar name after -cp as i have already added it to VertxTrapListener.jar that should be sufficient for running the verticle but thank for involvment